# Alternative verb for "to rest" to suggest an uncomfortable fit?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for an alternative to a specific meaning of the verb "to rest". After a (very) quick search, the definition which I found the best was:

> Be placed or supported so as to stay in a specified position.

I'm looking for an alternative to the word that implies that the position of the object (how it is resting and where it is resting) is uncomfortable. It's not the easiest to explain, so I'll give you the piece.

> The landline **rests** in the crook of her neck, and she speaks fast...
>
> The landline ____ in the crook of her neck, and she speaks fast...

To set the scene, this is essentially a description of the narrator's mother, who is forced to hold **the phone** uncomfortably as her hands are occupied.

Although I found **lie** (as in, *"The landline lies in the crook of her neck..."*, and this may seem more "negative", it doesn't sound right to me.

**EDIT 1:** A word which is better is *wedged:*

> The landline is **wedged** into the crook of her neck, and she speaks fast...

Alternatives and answers are still greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 2:** I'm also looking for something that isn't too much out of touch.

**EDIT 3:** Just to clarify, the *landline* is the phone itself, not the cord or anything. I didn't realise that it would cause any confusion.

Comment: The landline “chafes at the crook of her neck”

Comment: @Jim Thank you, but I think that the word "chafe" is generally associated with the uncomfortable rubbing of clothing on skin, and thus might cast some confusion, despite obvious context. I should have (and will have) altered the question to include the fact that I was looking for something rather "casual", or even colloquial.

Comment: Why is it important that you mention where the landline is resting? I assumed it was because it was uncomfortable and needed to set that scene. You should choose a word that brings out that reason rather than just saying that it is there.

Comment: It's just a detail, it's made clear (explicitly) that the reason that she is holding the landline in such a position is because her son has spilled his breakfast and she is trying to clean the mess.

Comment: Oh! By landline you mean the handset not the cord.  I didn’t get that at first. “landline” is not usually used to describe the phone itself, it is just used to describe the type of connection.

Comment: Ah, okay, I've often heard it used to describe the device itself, apologies. Yes, she has the phone device wedged in the nook of her shoulder, and is using her cheek to hold it there.